# Cannot static link ncurses with MinGW

Tags: ncurses, static-linking, mingw-w64

I am using Arch Linux and am attempting to cross-compile some code with ncurses library for Windows. Everything is fine if I let MinGW dynamically link with the .dll, but as soon as I add the `-static` flag, I get undefined references to all the ncurses functions (e.g. `__imp_initscr` or `__imp_stdscr`). How do I solve this?

My compilation command looks like this:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ test.cxx -O2 -s -lncursesw -o test
```

Comment: You'll probably have to configure/compile ncurses without DLLs (it builds static libraries without problem in a MinGW environment).  There's no tutorial...

Comment: Do you have only the file `libncursesw.dll.a` or is there also a file `libncursesw.a`?

Comment: @BrechtSanders I have both files.

Comment: If the undefined references in a static build start with `__imp_` then the issue must be that the header file defined `dllexport`, which should not be the case. Some libraries have a way around this by checking if something like `STATIC` is defined, so you could try building the static build with the `-DSTATIC` compiler flag, though you should check the `.h` file that defines `initscr` and `stdscr` to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by looking through the headers as mentioned by Brecht Sanders. The header defines `__declspec(dllexport)` unless `NCURSES_STATIC` is defined, so adding `-DNCURSES_STATIC` as a compile option fixes everything.

Comment: Here is a command that I've used: `gcc -I/mingw64/include/ncurses -o hello hello.c -lncurses -L/mingw64/bin -DNCURSES_STATIC`