# How to include and use any of the stuff in the subdirectories of `C:\msys64\mingw64\include`

Tags: c++, gcc, msys2

In my VSCode environment with working msys2 / mingW64 /gcc compilers i'm now trying to use ncurses / curses.

msys is in the default installpath, so gcc / g++ /gdb are in
`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`

As i understand it, the headerfiles being used by  directives are the ones in
`C:\msys64\mingw64\include`.
So in general i think this is a question how to properly include and use any of the stuff in the subdirectories of `C:\msys64\mingw64\include`

For my case with ncurses, in include directory there are two subdirectories with names `ncurses` and `ncursesw` with identical content.

To begin, i try with a very simple `helloCurses.cpp file

```
#include <ncurses/curses.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // init screen and sets up screen
    initscr();

    // print to screen
    printw("Hello World");

    // refreshes the screen
    refresh();

    // pause the screen output
    getch();

    // deallocates memory and ends ncurses
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

obviously the compiler can find the `ncurses/curses.h` file.
But it still doesn't compile.

I'm getting the error messages:

```
Executing task: C/C++: MingW g++.exe build active file 

Starting build...
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g D:\GitHub\Cpp-Code-priv\ncurses\helloCurses.cpp -o D:\GitHub\Cpp-Code-priv\ncurses\helloCurses.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mathias\AppData\Local\Temp\cc44BFtA.o: in function `main':
D:/GitHub/Cpp-Code-priv/ncurses/helloCurses.cpp:7: undefined reference to `__imp_initscr'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/GitHub/Cpp-Code-priv/ncurses/helloCurses.cpp:10: undefined reference to `__imp_printw'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/GitHub/Cpp-Code-priv/ncurses/helloCurses.cpp:13: undefined reference to `__imp_refresh'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/GitHub/Cpp-Code-priv/ncurses/helloCurses.cpp:16: undefined reference to `__imp_stdscr'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/GitHub/Cpp-Code-priv/ncurses/helloCurses.cpp:16: undefined reference to `__imp_wgetch'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/GitHub/Cpp-Code-priv/ncurses/helloCurses.cpp:19: undefined reference to `__imp_endwin'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
```

As far as I understand the linker will not find the ncurses library. This should be libncurses.a or libncurses.dll.

These files are in the directory C:\msys64\mingw64\lib.

In the end i like to compile with VSCode tasks.json, but to begin with, the commandline

```
gcc -I C:\msys64\mingw64\include\ncurses -L C:\msys64\mingw64\lib -lncurses helloCurses.cpp -o helloCurses.exe
```

didn't work either and still gives me the same errormessage.

I have been pointed to
[Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

I'm sure this will at some point become valuable information, but right now this isn't about the *order* of a multitude of probably codependent libraris. This is just about how to include a very first additional library not being basic enough to be includd by a simple
#include <stdio.h>, but still basic enough to be in the full toolchain being installed by`pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`

Comment: `undefined reference` indicates missing `-l`. `-l` must be to the right of `.cpp`, otherwise it has no effect. I suggest not adding redundant `-I` and `-L`, yours should be unnecessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 
I tried 
g++  helloCurses.cpp -l -o helloCurses.exe  || 
g++  -l helloCurses.cpp -o helloCurses.exe ||  
g++  helloCurses.cpp -o helloCurses.exe -l ||

and the same with -lncurses. it doesn't work for ma, and I'm not even aware of the meaning of  -l
I don't find it in g++ --help

Comment: @drescherjm
I' trying to read trough it and I'm sure at some point it may become a valuable information for me, but rigth now it isn'T.
Right now my problem is not with multiple libraries. M problem is how to get the very first additional library included hat is not in the most basic include path, being included with a simple #include <string> or so.  And i find it astonishing hard to find an aswer for that.

Comment: Is this supposed to be `c++` or `c`? If `c++` it should be `g++ helloCurses.cpp -lncurses -o helloCurses.exe`

Comment: ***MingW g++.exe build active file*** You did not edit your `tasks.json` and add the `"-lncurses,"` after "${file}," in the args:

Comment: it's supposed to be c++

Comment: i see i accidently wrote gcc in one of the comments which might be confusing. It should be g++, and with g++ it leads to the same errors as in the main text

Comment: @drescherjm `g++ helloCurses.cpp -lncurses -o helloCurses.exe` still gives me the same errors

Comment: i mean, it's a verry simple and short file, and it's just a standardinstallation of msys2 with mingw64. Does it work for you with the mentioned line?

Comment: I just tested and had the same errors. Then I tested on WSL / ubuntu and I had similar errors for the same code and fixed them but I have not fixed msys2 yet.

Comment: This got me past the linker errors on msys2: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67656787/cannot-static-link-ncurses-with-mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67656787/cannot-static-link-ncurses-with-mingw)